# What kinds of isomorphisms we have with $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{m}; \mathbb{C}^{n})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let us consider the space of complex-valued functions on $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{m})$. This is a Hilbert space and it is known that:
$$\overbrace{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{m})\otimes \cdots \otimes L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{m})}^{\text{$n$ times}} \cong L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{nm}).$$
Let $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{m};\mathbb{C}^{n})$ be the space of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$-valued $L^{2}$ functions. In this case, what kind(s) of isomorphism(s) do we have? For instance, do we have:
$$\overbrace{L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{m};\mathbb{C}^{n})\otimes \cdots \otimes L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{m};\mathbb{C}^{n})}^{\text{$n$ times}} \cong L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{nm};\mathbb{C}^{n}).$$
or some variation of it?

Answer (score 0):

You should have an isomorphism
$$L^2(\mathbb{R}^m;\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes k}\cong L^2(\mathbb{R}^{mk};\mathbb{C}^{nk})$$
for $k$ not necessarily equal to $n$. Herefore I suppose that you integrate $\mathbb{C}^n$-valued functions in their Euclidean norm.

The idea is, there exist a canonical isomorphism
$$
L^2(\mathbb{R}^m,\mathbb{C}^n)\cong L^2(\mathbb{R}^m\times\{1,\dots,n\})
$$
where $\{1,\dots,n\}$ is endowed with the counting measure (can you see that one?).

Then, you have the above isomorphism by $$(\mathbb{R}^m\times\{1,\dots,n\})^{\times k}=\mathbb{R}^{mk}\times\{1,\dots,m\}^{\times k},$$
where the measures fit together.